# Android - Messaging application layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-edittext

I am trying to reproduce the layout from the stock Android messaging app. I've done this using a list view with a custom adapter for the conversation and a fixed layout for the "send message" part. It looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
android:layout_marginRight="2dp" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/sendMsgLayout"
    android:overScrollMode="always"
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
</ListView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/sendMsgLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/list_divider" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/messageText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageSend"
        android:hint="@string/type_message"
        android:maxLines="3" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageSend"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/messageText"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/send" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my latest version of the layout, I've also used a LinearLayout as the parent with weight set to 1 for the list view.

[image: Layout picture]

The edit text has max 3 lines. The problem comes when one line is not enough to hold the text and the edit text grows. It covers part of the list view.
I think I should scroll the list view whenever the edit text grows in dimension but I could not achieve that.

[image: Overlap picture]

Any ideas on how to tackle this one ?

Comment: Add this two property android:singleLine="true",           android:scrollbars="vertical" and remove this one android:maxLines="3".

Comment: You can try putting the bottom view as a footer on the ListView rather than as a separate part of the layout.

Comment: @Haresh He still wants 3 lines, he just don't want Brad Pitt's face to be covered when he writes 3 lines. I havn't used ListView that much but wouldn't it work to wrap the ListView and sendMsgLayout in a LinearLayout?

Comment: @Haresh I want the edit text to have 3 lines.

Comment: @GabeSechan I tried that, but when used as a footer the bottom view only appears when you scroll down the list. The footer should be present at all times.

Comment: @Rawa I tried the approach with the LinearLayout... the result is the same.

Comment: @andreid does setting the transcriptMode to normal on the listView android:transcriptMode="normal" solve this issue?

Comment: @Rawa Yes, that was my mistake... I was left over with the attribute "overScrollMode" on the list view from some early attempts. This was causing the bad scroll effect. "android:transcriptMode" works well with both normal and alwaysScroll. I will update my post accordingly.
You can post it as an answer so I can accept it as the correct answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @andreid great, please accept my answer so we can help others with the same problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the listview transcriptMode to normal, alternativly alwaysScroll and as pointed out by @andreid remove android:overScrollMode="always".

```
android:transcriptMode="normal"
```

or in code:

```
listView.setTranscriptMode(AbsListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_NORMAL);
```

Comment: As Rawa pointed out, there was a mistake in the original layout on the listview attributes. Replacing android:overScrollMode with android:transcriptMode fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</ListView>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@color/list_divider" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/sendMsgLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/messageText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:hint="@string/type_message"
        android:maxLines="3" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageSend"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/send" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: As I said in the original post, I tried the approach with LinearLayouts and weight set to 1.. the result is the same (I tried your code, same behavior).

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:overScrollMode="always"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sendMsgLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/messageText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/type_message"
            android:maxLines="3" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageSend"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/send" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```